# Fast Python Code for saving data on spheric surface points

Tags: python

I have some Data that i wanna save on the coordinates of the surface of a sphere.So i get 3 coordinates, with a radius and data. And i wanna add this data to every coordinate on a sphere with the given radius around this point. But the code is very slow, any idea how to get it faster?

```
def Grid(x, y, z, r, data):
    global voxelGrid   
    phi = 0
        #set the surface here
        z += surfaceZ

        while phi <= (2*math.pi):
            eta = math.pi * 2 / 3
            while eta <= math.pi:
                xx = x + r * math.sin(eta) * math.cos(phi)
                yy = y + r * math.sin(eta) * math.sin(phi)
                zz = z + r * math.cos(eta)

                xx = int(round((xx)))
                yy = int(round((yy)))
                zz = int(round((zz)))
                voxelGrid[xx][yy][zz] += data

                eta += 1/10 * math.pi

            phi += 1/10 * math.pi
```

So my first idea, was to make kind of a look up table, because the data i have is like this: I get a point X,Y,Z and than some different Radiuses and Data. The radiuses for the different x,y,z positions are always the same, so that this calculation will be done every time for the same numbers:

```
r * math.sin(eta) * math.cos(phi)
r * math.sin(eta) * math.sin(phi)
r * math.cos(eta)
```

So I tried to do some lookup tables, but this just made the code even slower(probably because i use global Variables):

```
def Grid(x, y, z, RadiusIndex, data):
    global voxelGrid
    global Phi
    global Eta
    global XX
    global YY
    global ZZ
    etaIndex = 0
    phiIndex = 0

        z += surfaceZ

        while phiIndex < len(Phi):

            while etaIndex < len(Eta):


                xx = x + XX[RadiusIndex][etaIndex][phiIndex]
                yy = y + YY[RadiusIndex][etaIndex][phiIndex]
                zz = z + ZZ[RadiusIndex][etaIndex]

                xx = int(round((xx)))
                yy = int(round((yy)))
                zz = int(round((zz)))
                voxelGrid[xx][yy][zz] += data
                etaIndex += 1

            phiIndex += 1
            etaIndex = 0
```

I did a measurement with some small testData and cProfile:

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.449    1.449 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    1.449    1.449    1.449    1.449 confutures.py:8(Grid)
        1    0.000    0.000    1.449    1.449 {built-in method builtins.exec}
      168    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method math.cos}
      168    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method math.sin}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

I do not really understand what is: built-in method builtins.exec
I think my main Problem ist the global numpy array, is there any way to do that better?

Comment: Are your `phi` and `eta` variables supposed to represent the other two polar coordinates? I'm a little confused about what you expect the final result to look like.

Comment: using a profiler where is the most time spend? In the calculation or the update of the voxelGrid? You can move the global var to local by assigment: `localPhi = Phi`. Maybe using shorter variable names instead of `RadiusIndex`, less dictionary lookup time. No need to store the `int(round(..)` result in a var, use it immediate in the `[int(round(xx))]`. Will you ever get a second hit for the same xx,yy,zz, if not no need to do the `+=`

Comment: to get a nicer point distribution use the points on a subdivided sphere. Also less points to calculate.

Comment: PatrickHaugh on this Picture you can see what my eta and what my phi is: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/Kugelkoord-def.svg

@rioV8 no i will try. but i never used a profiler! 

But is there another way to do that, because my way with the +1/10pi seems very strange for me. also its not very accurate, because it should be dependent of the radius. bigger radius needs more 'steps' between the angles, because there is more distance between them.

Comment: η=eta, θ=theta. You want to get the whole sphere around x,y,z but you only run (th)eta from 2/3π to π. for profiling see https://zapier.com/engineering/profiling-python-boss/

Comment: Yes @rioV8  I actually dont want the whole sphere, just 120 digree opening in negative z direction. is there any chance to run the code in multicore? Since i have a global var ?

Comment: for `voxelGrid` I use `defaultdict`s and I can do 1000 `Grid()` calls in 0.25s. How many calls do you need because you say it is slow? Using the line_profiler I found that any line in the inner while takes about the same time. If you go multi core you need an expensive merge operation of all the individual `voxelGrid` variables.

Comment: You think that defaultdicts are faster than numpy arrays? because i thought numpys are written in c or something.. you mean how many times I add data to my array? with some real data it would be: 320 * 120000 = 38.4 million times..

Comment: @Oroshimaru: I used defaultdict because there was no code/example for voxelGrid. dict and defaultdict are also implemented in C. I don't get your calculation: phi loop 20 steps, theta loop 4 steps gives 80 calculations per Grid() call. Do you do 38e6 calls to Grid() or updates of the voxelGrid? If you are not stuck to Python you might try a GPU version.